# rails after_create with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, after-create

I have this code in my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :set_user_full_name
  .........
private

  def set_user_full_name
    self.name = "Test name"
  end
end
```

But when I create a user the name attribute is nil. I tried adding name to

create and update strong params but no luck.

```
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << [:name]
devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:name]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`after_create` callback is executed after inserting user data in db.

in your code, `name` is not actually inserted.

```
user = User.create(some_attiributes)
user.name     #=> "Test name"

user.reload
user.name     #=> nil
```

If you want to insert name attribute, use `before_create` callback.
It assign name value before insert

**Updated:**

If User has `first_name` and `last_name` attribute,

```
before_create :set_user_full_name

def set_user_full_name
    self.name = "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

But If User does not have `first_name` and `last_name` attribute, you should handle in controller.

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :set_name_param, only: [:create]

  private
  def set_name_param
    params[:user][:name] = "#{params[:user][:first_name]} #{params[:user][:last_name]}"
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks that actually woked. However, I have `firstname` and `lastname` attributes in sign up form and my plan is to join the two to become the `name` attribute. How should I do that?

Thanks a lot again :)

Comment: I updated answer! it is rough code, kinda concept for understanding.